# Why did I get "Display is not capable of DPMS"?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

I want to test code a button. However it just gave me the result: Display is not capable of DPMS. Why?

```
from tkinter import *
# tkinter

class Root(Tk):
  def __init__(self):
  # define self
    super(Root, self),__init__()
    self.title("Tkinter Button")
    # title of new window
    self.minsize(640,400)
    # size of button
    self.wm_iconbitmap('icon.ico')




    button = Button(self, text = "Click Me")
    # text on the button
    button.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
    # location in the new window opened

    root = Root()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Michael, how about this?

Comment: I just coded this myself and it got the same warning again

Comment: I solved my first one already. But when I tried my second one the same problem came out again

Comment: Is this code really formatted exactly as on your machine? You are creating an instance of `Root` inside of `Root`.

Comment: as in the "end of line" 3 words, no. I put it in only to show that the line ends there and it will go on to the next line

Comment: I don't understand that answer. Let me be more specific: are the last two lines (`root = Root()` and `root.mainloop()` supposed to be inside of `__init__`? They shouldn't be. It's important that the code in the question has the same indentation as your actual code.

Comment: Thanks bro for your comment, I will try it out now

Comment: will this also work if I do not use root?

Comment: There must be a root window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Display is not capable of DPMS` is not an error, it is just a warning, your code will work anyway. Your actual issue here is that you are not `mainloop`ing the right `tk.Root`.

You are probably stuck in infinite recursion, because you are initializing a `Root` object within the initialization of a `Root` object.

```python
class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # you are initializing another Root object here!
        root = Root()  
        # that will itself initialize another Root object,
        # and that will itself initialize another Root object, etc.

        root.mainloop()  # this statement will never be reached
```

What you actually want is calling `mainloop` for your newly created `Root` object. In the `__init__` method, this newly created object is just `self`. This code should work as you expect.

```python
class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Tkinter Button")
        self.minsize(640,400)
        self.wm_iconbitmap('icon.ico')

        button = Button(self, text = "Click Me")
        button.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

        self.mainloop()
```

Also consider simply running `mainloop` from outside the object itself, it is generally undesirable to do so in Tkinter's object initialization itself

```python
# remove self.mainloop() from Root.__init__ first
root = Root()
root.mainloop()  # better
```

---

Side note: you wrote `super(Root, self),__init__()` with a comma instead of a dot, that should raise a `NameError` when instanciating `Root`. The right syntax to initialize the object with the parent class is

```python
super(Root, self).__init__()
```

Or simply, [using modern syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)

```python
super().__init__()
```

Comment: So what does the "remove self.mainloop() from Root.__init__" mean?

Comment: I am actually lost so I must asking it

Comment: Just do not write `self.mainloop()` in the `Root.__init__`. You'd have this https://pastebin.com/34z50whE